# Books, Videos, Tutorials to learn about different investment options in the financial domain

Tags: books

I am a software developer joining a hedge fund this week and I dont have much knowledge of finance and want to learn everything about it. I know the basic investment options of shares and bonds, however i want to know how people invest today, what different markets are present and which investment is best in what scenarios. Please suggest me books, videos or tutorials to start with. As of now i just known investopedia who offers such learning materials but would appreciate if you can tell me some more.

Thank you friends for always being kind and helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Those are some very broad questions and I don't think I can answer them completely, but I will add what I can. Barron's Finance and Investment Handbook is the best reference book I have found. It provides a basic description/definition for every type of investment available. It covers stocks, preferred stocks, various forms of bonds as well as mortgage pools and other exotic instruments. It has a comprehensive dictionary of finance terms as well. I would definitely recommend getting it.

The question about how people invest today is a huge one. There are people who simply put a monthly amount into a mutual fund and simply do that until retirement on one side and professional day traders who move in and out of stocks or commodities on a daily basis on the other.

Answer (score 2):

Just by chance I recently encountered this link - [Do It Yourself MFE](http://blog.hiremebecauseimsmart.com/post/2860511335/design-your-own-mfe), which describes an attempt to self-educate to the level of Master of Financial Engineering. It lists books, online courses, etc. which I think may be interesting for you too.

Answer (score 1):

Investopedia does have tutorials about investments in different asset classes. Have you read them ? If you had heard of CFA, you can read their material if you can get hold of it or register for CFA. Their material is quite extensive and primarily designed for newbies.

[This](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0446578479)  is one helluva book and advice coming from persons who have showed and proved their tricks. And the good part is loads of advice in one single volume. And what they would suggest is probably opposite of what you would be doing in a hedge fund.

And you can always trust google to fish out resources at the click of a button.